# How to disable and re-enable label

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

In the below code, I have a label named `card` with a mouse click event. I only want the click event to implement once. Meaning it will implement the first time I click the label, but not the following times. How do I do this? I imagine I must disable its Listener.

```
private void cardMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    // displays backside of each flashcards when label (flashcard) is clicked   
    i++;
    card.setText(cardB[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Andrei I just rephrased it. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Why not just use a boolean to remember if your card is flipped or not? Depending on that, you can run this bit of code or not...

Comment: A JLabel's state won't effect the MouseListener been triggered, normally we'd suggest using an undecorated button instead.

Comment: You could look into using `Timer.schedule` for a one time event by setting the delay to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we all would do the same.
It's really simple. Just declare a boolean then change its status when you click the first time.

```
    boolean labelClicked = false;
    private void cardMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    // displays backside of each flashcards when label (flashcard) is clicked   
      if(!labelClicked){
      i++;
      card.setText(cardB[i]);
      labelClicked=true;
      }
         else{
        //doNothing
         }
    }
```